# Apache Kerberos token error

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, kerberos, mod-auth-kerb

Im trying to setup a simple file directory share on my apache, which is kerberized to handle KDC tickets,

I am getting these errors in my Apacche error log when I try to access the shared files via Chrome browser on my workstation,

---

```
Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.390610 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1598): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.390657 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1230): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] Acquiring creds for HTTP/web01.CORP.local@CORP.LOCAL
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.392259 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1352): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API 
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.392296 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1368): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] Client didn't delegate us their credential
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.392305 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1396): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] **Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.**
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.392312 2017] [auth_kerb:debug] [pid 8140] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1091): [client 192.168.2.136:58703] GSS-API **major_status:00070000, minor_status:00000000**
[Fri Dec 08 16:59:50.392328 2017] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 8140] [client 192.168.2.136:58703] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible (, Unknown error)*


    ----------
```

I have a Windows 10 workstation thats on my corp AD,
my Apache is on Centos 7, httpd-2.4.10

I created a service account for my Apache server using mksutil and copied over the generated keytab to the Apache server, /etc/httpd/

Testing done so far:

1. test basic connection from Apache server to Domain

```
    [root@web01 /etc/httpd]# kinit first.last
    Password for first.last@CORP.LOCAL:
    [root@web01 /etc/httpd]#
```

2. check if Utility Account called 'web01.httpd' was generated on AD, and its there, also checking it via KLIST

```
    [root@web01 /etc/httpd]# klist -kte /etc/httpd/httpd.keytab
    Keytab name: FILE:/etc/httpd/httpd.keytab
    KVNO Timestamp         Principal
    ---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 web01.httpd@CORP.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac)
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 web01.httpd@CORP.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 web01.httpd@CORP.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 HTTP/web01.CORP.local@CORP.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac)
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 HTTP/web01.CORP.local@CORP.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
       2 12/08/17 10:16:28 HTTP/web01.CORP.local@CORP.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

```
3. check if KVNO shows a number,
```

```
    
        [root@web01 /etc/httpd]# kvno HTTP/web01.CORP.local
        kvno HTTP/web01.corp.local@CORP.LOCAL
        HTTP/web01.corp.local@CORP.LOCAL: kvno = 2
```

```
    4. checked my Apache config,
```

```
        
            LoadModule auth_kerb_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_kerb.so

                
                    ServerName webfiles
                    ServerAlias webfiles.corp.local
                    DocumentRoot /opt/webfiles
                    LogLevel Debug
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
                

                
                    ServerName webfiles
                    ServerAlias webfiles.corp.local
                    DocumentRoot /opt/webfiles

                    LogLevel Debug
                    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/webfiles_error
                    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/webfiles_access common

                    SSLEngine On
                    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/private/web01.CORP.local.pem
                    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/web01.CORP.local.pem
                    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/CORP_intermediate_ca.crt


                    
                      AuthzSendForbiddenOnFailure On
                      Options +Indexes
                      AllowOverride None
                      Order allow,deny
                      Allow from all
                      AuthName "kerb access"
                      AuthType Kerberos
                      KrbAuthRealms CORP.LOCAL
                      KrbServiceName HTTP/web01.corp.local@CORP.LOCAL
                      Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/httpd.keytab
                      KrbMethodK5Passwd off
                      KrbLocalUserMapping on
                      KrbSaveCredentials on
                      SSLRequireSSL
                      #AuthGroupFile /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-access-groups
                      Require valid-user
```

```
      5. checked the /etc/krb5.conf for proper domain info, it looks good,
```

```
            [libdefaults]
             default_realm = CORP.LOCAL
             dns_lookup_realm = true
             dns_lookup_kdc = true
             ticket_lifetime = 10h
             renew_lifetime = 7d
             forwardable = true
             kdc_timesync = true
             ccache_type = 4
             proxiable = true
             fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
             default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
             verify_ap_req_nofail = true

            [realms]
             CORP.LOCAL = {
              kdc = CORP.local
              admin_server = dom01.corp.local
             }

            [domain_realm]
             CORP.local     = CORP.LOCAL
             .CORP.local    = CORP.LOCAL
             .dr.CORP.local = CORP.LOCAL
             .test.local           = CORP.LOCAL
             .dmz.local            = CORP.LOCAL
             .prod.local           = CORP.LOCAL
```

Dont know where else to look, my workstation Internet Options - Local Sites- are configured to authenticate to my domains,

[image]

Still getting the NTLM error message

Comment: In /etc/krb5.conf, under [realms], put the fully-qualified host name of your KDC.

Comment: On your Windows 10 machine, what output does the following return:  setspn -Q HTTP/web01.corp.local

Comment: ^C
C:\WINDOWS\system32>setspn -Q HTTP/web01.corp.local
Checking domain DC=CORP,DC=local
CN=web01.httpd,OU=Kerberos,OU=Utility Accounts,OU=CORP-Users,DC=CORP,DC=local
        HTTP/web01.corp.local
   
-----------------------------

Existing SPN found

Comment: Ok, got it.  In /etc/krb5.conf, under [realms], have you edited it yet so it has the fully-qualified host name of your KDC?

Comment: I would also advise that under Internet Options - Local Sites - add *.corp.local.

Comment: You still there?

Comment: yes thank you for the help, i got it to work, heres my full notes on how to set this up,

https://sites.google.com/site/mrxpalmeiras/kerberos-sso-configuration